# Run a list of commands in a script

Tags: terminal

Trying to run this and get no such file or folder even though the individual files work in terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill Microsoft Teams

rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/blob_storage/*
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/Cache/*
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/databases/*
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/GPUCache/*
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/IndexedDB/*
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/Local Storage/*

echo "Clearing Microsoft Teams Cache"
```

I know this must be basic stuff but not a Mac user normally.

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 6):

## Quoted Spaces

A couple of lines need quoting to deal with spaces:

```
pkill Microsoft Teams
```

Should read:

```
pkill "Microsoft Teams"
```

and `Local Storage` needs a slash to become `Local\ Storage`.

### Absolute Paths

If you continue to encounter problems, try expanding the `~` and use absolute/full paths. This can solve many problems and allows scripts to be run from within other tools like `cron` or `launchd`.

## ShellCheck

A useful tool to know about is [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). This online or offline tool can help point out common shell script problems.

Comment: Shells know about tilde expansions.  Don't ever expect them to work anywhere else.

Comment: @MarcWilson the issue is that shells run from different contexts may have different values for $HOME and thus expand a bare tilde differently. Generally, if commands don't work as expected in a script, checking whether relevant environment variables are as expected is a good diagnostic step.